# Sending message with def function in on_message

Tags: python, function, discord.py, python-asyncio

How do I send a message in a () as I mentioned in the picture?
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyC1Z.png)

Code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if "!" in message.content:
    
        await message.channel.send("selam naber...")
        
        zzz1=await message.channel.send("fai.")
        zzz2=await message.channel.send("hit...")
        
       def a():
            zzz2
        a()
```

This is an example to understand
(It doesn't happen when you do it like in the picture.)

I am sorry for my English

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be sure to read [ask], and remember to [not post code as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: @CiN_ALi May I suggest that you remove the image and replace it with the code you are interested in. Having the code may help you better form your question and allow others to [Re-Produce the example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) too! Images are not always useful to all S.O. users. See [Images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: @oaxacamatt loaded code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `a` function should be a coroutine as you're using the `await` keyword inside of it

```py
async def a():
    await message.channel.send("something")
```

To call it you also need to await it

```py
await a()
```